# Notation for the element of a set of functions, where the functions are predicates.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, predicate-logic

What is the best way of specifying an element of a set of predicates on a variable $x$, which is a member of a set $X$?

By convention, I understand that for any sets X and Y, the set of all functions $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is denoted $Y^X$.

My preference would be to write $ p\in \Psi( x )$ specifying that $p$ is a predicate taking $x$ as a predicate variable, and $\Psi$ as the set of all predicates relating to $x \in X$. Is there anything wrong with this?

I would have thought this to be more intuitive than something like this; $ p\in \Psi$ where $\Psi( y ) = \{{\text{true}, \text{false}}\}^X$.

Comment: In FOL, *predicates* are part of the language; thus, they are specified at the start, "outside" of the system. We use them to build formulas.

Comment: Thus, a "typical" specification for a FOL language needs: $\text {Var}$ the set of individual variables: $\{ x,y,z,\ldots \}$, a set (usually finite) of predicate symbols $\text {Pred} = \{ P_1,P_2, \ldots, P_n \}$ and similarly for individual constants and function symbols.

Comment: If you want to consider the *semantics* of a predicate $P$, we need an *interpretation* $I$ based on a *domain* $D$ (usually not empty). In this case $P^I \subseteq D$ for unary predicate, $P^I \subseteq D \times D$ for binary predicates, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Mauro. I am trying to express something in the field of artificial intelligence. I understand what you mean when you say that that predicates are outside the system. However, if I want to say something about predicates using set theory in some meta-mathematical sense, I might need to go back to basics, and try to understand how to express this. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: In that sense, a (unary) *predicate* $P$ is a function from domain $D$ to $\{ \text {true}, \text {false} \}$, i.e. $P \in \{ \text {true}, \text {false} \}^D$ that maps each element $d \in D$ to $\text {true}$ or $\text {false}$ according if $P$ holds of it or not.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again.